# how to invoke a spring component from Java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `rowcallBackHandler` from JDBCTemplate, but as I am using the `new` operator I am not able to get any Spring component inside the `rowbackhandler`. Basically, I need to iterate over big result set.

I need to call a method after every 1000 records, but I am not able to invoke the method; the autowiring or component scan is not working. How to inject a spring bean inside a normal java class?

Comment: You are not providing enough details to help you. What kind of application is this? what is your Spring configuration? can we take a look at a piece of code where you are having the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to dynamically inject your rowcallbackHandler because your making the object every time you execute the SQL.

As a general best practice Spring dependency injection should really only be used on singleton-like objects (ie Services, DAO, etc..). That is callback like objects should not need or use dependency injection. Instead you need to wire your surrounding singleton-like object (@Service,@Controller,@Repository ... etc) with what your callbackhandler needs and then access the dependencies through constructor or regular-closure-like-lexical scoping (I forgot what its called in Java). I don't know what your skill level is in Java but it sounds like you might not know about anonymous classes.

Here is an example using anonymous classes.

```
@Service
public MyService {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate template;
    @Autowired
    Something something;

    public void doSomething() {
        template.query("select * from something", new RowCallbackHandler() {
            public void processRow(ResultSet rs) {
                System.out.println(something);
                //actually do something
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That being said you can auto inject objects with `new Blah()` but it requires `@Configurable` AspectJ magic (don't do this unless you know what your doing).

Comment: Seem that you answer is more full, I deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

To use spring beans in normal Java class , you need `ApplicationContext` and then call `getBean` pass it the `bean id` which you declared in your `application-context.xml`. E.g.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
Foo foo = ctx.getBean("beanId", Foo.class);
```

Comment: If I tried to create the bean like, I am getting null value for the beans autowired inside the bean, in this case if Foo class have any autowired bean, it is not getting initialized.

Comment: @Hari could you paste you application-context.xml, because it should work fine, i replicate locally the behavior as you specified and there seems to be no problem with Autowired or Component